# Convert mixed table to array Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have a table which is all numbers as read from excel using readtable. Some of the numbers come through within apostrophes such as '0.084' etc. This is because of the excel sheets being messy with words appearing in some columns but outside the table data. Using isstring returns 0. 
My primary aim is to turn the table into 3D array (is it possible to create a 3D table?). How do I convert the cells that appear as 'x' to numbers so that I can build my 3D array (from several of these tables).

For example Var11 in this table comes through as one of the offenders:
[image]

different tables may have different locations for these cells.
 Trying to convert the entire table to array gives an error:

```
 B = table2array(z);
Error using table2array (line 27)
Cannot concatenate the table variables 'Var3' and 'Var11', because
their types are double and cell.
```

Comment: Show a screenshot of the imported table from your Matlab workspace, or paste in a small subset of your data to give us better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

`ischar('0.084')` returns 1, and there is no isstring. To get value from `table`, you use cell array notion - A{i,j}. Most of cell stuff will not work though and you cannot use cellfun. So I suggest a simple double loop:

```
for i = 1 : N
   for j = 1 : M
      val = A{i,j};
      if (ischar(val))
         val = str2num(val);
      end
      M(i,j) = val;
   end
end
```

There is likely a more elegant solution. You can search for it here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html

To convert, use `str2num`. Note that Matlab operates on doubles by default and you will get double.

3D arrays are indeed possible - for example zeros(10,10,3) will create 10x10x3 array of zeros (of double type).

Comment: Thanks. If my table is "z" then ischar(z(1,9)), for one of the offending cells, returns 0 rather than 1. Hence my difficulty in converting the whole table to array as I cannot determine one type from another.

Comment: What does whos tell for `z`? Cell? If it is cell, then you should use `cellfun(...)` to operate on multiple data elements at the same time. Or use z{1,9} to get value inside of cell (string in this case).

Comment: whos('z') returns class table

Comment: Aha I see it in example too now. In this case you can use ischar(z{1,9}), like if it was cell (but it is not! This will work, most of cell stuff doesn't). So, to solve this problem, you should use a double loop to get over all elements of the table, and convert them to numbers as needed.

Comment: unfortunately ischar(z{1,9}) still returns 0. So unable to distinguish it from the others.

Comment: Hum, what type is that z{1,9} then? It looks like a string in the example you posted. But yeah, as the string contains those ', it cannot be parsed directly using str2num. You need to parse like: str2num(z{1,9}(2:end-1))

Comment: thanks zizy. But unfortunately ischar(val) also returns 0. Even if I convert the table via  B = table2cell(z) first and apply above to B.